# View is not updated after the $http async call when using controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularjs and I am trying to use the controllerAs syntax as I am from Java background and this would make more sense to me but I am having trouble understanding the digest loop.

I am trying to do a http call and update the variable in the controller.When I am using $scope in controller the view is updated after the data is received but when I am using the controllerAs syntax the view is not updated.

Codepen with $scope Syntax

http://codepen.io/eternal15/pen/BzANEw?editors=1111

```
  <html>
  <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    {{output}}
    <button ng-click="onClick()">Test</button>
  </body>

</html>
//JS FILE
angular.module("Test", []).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.output = "Loading";
  $scope.onClick = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data){ 
      $scope.output = "worked!!";
      console.log($scope.output);
    })
  }
}]);
```

Codepen with controllerAs Syntax (View not updated)

http://codepen.io/eternal15/pen/yJKoaZ?editors=1011

```
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
    {{test.output}}
    <button ng-click="test.onClick()">Test</button>
  </body>

</html>
//JS File
angular.module("Test", []).controller('testCtrl', ['$http', function($http){
  this.output = "Loading";
  this.onClick = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data){ 
      this.output = "worked!!";
      console.log(this.output);
    })
  }
}]);
```

I have read about the controllerAs syntax and I think it would add the object (test in the example above) under scope and thus the variables are accessible using (test) object.

So the digest loop runs after $http call because the view is updated in the first example using $scope. Since the digest loop is executed the object test in the second example should also be updated right?

Also i tried to inject $scope and do $scope.$apply() and that also didn't work and it gave me this error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Although i could go back to using the $scope format, I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or should I add other statements to watch the variables and update the values manually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` has a different meaning inside function. Assign `this` to a variable and use it. Try:

```
angular.module("Test", []).controller('testCtrl', ['$http', function($http){
  var vm = this;
  vm.output = "Loading";
  vm.onClick = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data){ 
      vm.output = "worked!!";
      console.log(vm.output);
    })
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of javascripts closures. When defining a new function you're creating a new scope, hence the keyword `this` has a new meaning for each new scope.

To solve this, define the controllers scope at the top of your controller. Common names used are either `vm`or `$ctrl`.

Your controller would then look somehting like this:

```
angular.module("Test", []).controller('testCtrl', ['$http', function( $http){
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.output = "Loading";
  $ctrl.onClick = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(data){ 
      $ctrl.output = "worked!!";
      //$scope.$apply();
    })
  }
}]);
```